# target a slide with jquery cycle 2 plugin with callback

Tags: callback, jquery-cycle

I'm using the following callback event with the jquery cycle 2 plugin, what it does at the moment is fade in `.watch1` after the slideshow has completed transitioning to the next slide. But how do I target a specific slide, so the fadeIn only occurs after the slide 1 has completed transitioning?

```
$( '.cycle-slideshow' ).on( 'cycle-after', function(event, optionHash, outgoingSlideEl, incomingSlideEl, forwardFlag) {
            $( '.watch1' ).fadeIn(2000);
```

});

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to bind a variable for your slide like this:

```
$('.cycle-slideshow').on('cycle-after',function(e, optionHash, outgoingSlideEl, incomingSlideEl, forwardFlag) {

    var active = $(incomingSlideEl)

    if (active.is('#slide1')) {

        $( '.watch1' ).fadeIn(2000);

    }

});
```

This means that after slide 1 is done animating in, your .watch1 element will fade in.  I believe this is what you need.